# Smooth pullback of holonomic D-modules is fully faithful

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, d-modules

Let $X$ and $Y$ be (not necessarily smooth) algebraic varieties over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, and suppose we have a smooth surjective map $f: X \to Y$ of relative dimension $d$ with connected fibers. Denote by $D_{hol}(X)$ and $D_{hol}(Y)$ their derived categories of holonomic D-modules. Then the derived functor $$f^*[d]: D_{hol}(Y) \longrightarrow D_{hol}(X)$$ is t-exact, and in particular preserves the abelian category of holonomic D-modules.

$\mathbf{Question}$: Is $f^*[d]$ fully faithful when restricted to the abelian category of holonomic D-modules?

This result is true if we replace "holonomic D-modules" everywhere by "perverse sheaves," but I'm wondering if a similar proof works for D-modules (the proof I know of is in "Faisceaux pervers" by Beilinson, Bernstein, and Deligne, Prop. 4.2.5). Ultimately, I would be very happy if a result like this was essentially a consequence of the existence of a six functor formalism.

Comment: Yes. This can be proved by induction on the dimension of Y, using Beilinson's gluing theorem together with the compatibility of unipotent nearby/vanishing cycles with (shifted) smooth pullback.

Comment: @Satan'sMinion Any chance you’d be willing to provide some more details?

Comment: @Gabriel I believe this is indeed true, and the same proof works. Essentially, since the category of holonomic D-modules is Artinian, we can reduce to the case where the base is smooth and the sheaf is a connection. Then check that the adjunction map is an iso on fibers using Poincare duality; the fact that the connection might have irregular singularities is immaterial. Thanks for the contact info, I will send a message when I have a chance